# Multidex doesn't work after enable proguard and minifyEnabled=true

Tags: java, android, debugging, proguard, android-multidex

After enabling proguard and setting the minifyEnabled=true i got this error on the activity startup:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.code--fknQZuBbRxyDlzudklbZw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mypackage.code--fknQZuBbRxyDlzudklbZw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.mypackage.code--fknQZuBbRxyDlzudklbZw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:977)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6030)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1764)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.mypackage.code--fknQZuBbRxyDlzudklbZw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.mypackage.code--fknQZuBbRxyDlzudklbZw==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.mypackage.code--fknQZuBbRxyDlzudklbZw==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:93)
```

this is my gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mypackage.code"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 17
        versionName "0.25"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled true

            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
```

i have imported the multidex library because my min target is 19

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
```

and on the android manifest i have added the MultiDexApplication following the documentation:

```
   <application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```

infact everythings works, but after enabling proguard the problems began.

this is my rule about multidex that i tried on proguard:

```
####multidex
-keep  class android.** { *; }
-keepclassmembernames class android.**
-dontnote android.**
-keep class android.support.multidex.**
-keepclassmembernames class android.support.multidex.**{*;}
-keepclassmembers class android.support.multidex.** {*;}
-keep public class android.support.multidex.**
```

do you have any idea? i need to obfuscate the code so disabling proguard and the minifyEnabled is not a possible option.

thanks!

Comment: multidex doesn't need any proguard rules tweaking it works without it.

Comment: have you added `MultiDex.install(this);` in your  Application class's `attachBaseContext` method? and clean and rebuild?

Comment: @MohammedJunaid i have added that rules, because withtout doesn't work too, the error reamain the same, with or without that rules.

about MultiDex.install(this) according to the google doc, is not needed because i'm not overidding the application, so should be enough the application declared on the android manifest:
 android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication.

and yes i have tried many times to clean and rebuild : (

Comment: Did you try `Clean and Rebuild`, and sometimes weirdly `disabling instant run` also does the trick.

Comment: yep i tried many times to clean and rebuild, and the instant run is already disabled, at the moment i'm stuck.

Comment: are you using any androidX libraries?

Comment: no, i'm not using the androidX libraries, but i discovered that the problem was this proguard rules:
-overloadaggressively

now i have this problemm of course without proguard everythings works:
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mypackage/com.mypachage.SplashScreenActivity}: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: getInstance []
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2955)

Comment: Update your question with relevant details such as the activity in question.